# SQL code for new column names and aggregate totals by date

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

```
SELECT Count (*) AS Amount FROM Tbl_Original  WHERE AcctNumber IS NOT NULL AND dateadded between '20151001' AND '20151031'
UNION
SELECT Count (*) FROM Tbl_Original  WHERE AcctNumber IS NOT NULL AND dateadded between '20151101' AND '20151130'
UNION
SELECT Count (*) FROM Tbl_Original  WHERE AcctNumber IS NOT NULL AND dateadded between '20151201' AND '20151231'`
```

Tbl_Original

```
AcctNu      Dateadded
-----------------------
qwe56755    10/22/2015
qwe33455    10/06/2015
qwe09967    11/17/2015
```

Trying to get this:

```
Month      Amount
-------------------
October    2
November   1
```

Using SQL for this (in Access).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the constant month names for this kind of query.

```
SELECT 'October' AS Month, Count (*) AS Amount FROM Tbl_Original  WHERE AcctNumber IS NOT NULL AND dateadded between '20151001' AND '20151031'
UNION
SELECT 'November' AS Month, Count (*) AS Amount FROM Tbl_Original  WHERE AcctNumber IS NOT NULL AND dateadded between '20151101' AND '20151130'
UNION
SELECT 'December' AS Month, Count (*) AS Amount FROM Tbl_Original  WHERE AcctNumber IS NOT NULL AND dateadded between '20151201' AND '20151231'
```

Although a **crosstab query**, based on a query that extracts the month from the date field, might be more suitable for what you want.

Comment: The problem with trying to do the crosstab (I think, but I may be wrong) is that I am working with an inherited database. There is some very bad table designs that I have to work around. For instance, the "dateadded" field is coded as "text" and not "date" and of course it is linked to other tables and queries. So I am assigning months for the ranges given and then working on somehow displaying the data. Thanks, again